# SWIFT : UITableView passing all cell's data(TextField & Label) to UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Im developing a project called Order Online App using Xcode. Is it possible to **passing all static cell's data(TextField(section 1's cell) & Label(section 2's cell)** from **UITableView to UIViewController using ButtonItem?**.

**E.g User Sign Up Step :**

- User must fill the form in TableView >>
- User Clicks Next button >>
- The user's detail will be in ViewController. User's data was collected from TableView for confirmation.
- User can go Back to edit the detail. >>
- Sign Up.

**Question :** I tried ctrl+Drag UITableview to UIViewController but it did not show the "Show Detail" Segue. What should I do?

Sorry for my bad english :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried dragging from a cell instead of the table?

and yes, you can pass data with a segue too, best wrap it in a class.

Comment: yes i did. In ViewController, im using label text to get data from uitableview (textfield and label). but it appeared blank page. what segue is it?